# MKAnnotation display all pin titles without clicking

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am adding multiple annotations programmatically like this:

```
- (void)addAnnotations{
    NSInteger i;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < [storeLatitude count] ; i ++ ){
        location.latitude = [[storeLatitude objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
        location.longitude = [[storeLongitude objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];

        MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:[listOfStores objectAtIndex:i] andCoordinate:location];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
        [newAnnotation release];    
    }
}
```

Is it possible to display the title for all pins without clicking on them?

Answer (score 7):

Declare an array to store all annotation and use MKMapView's setSelectedAnnotations:(NSArray *) method

```
- (void)addAnnotations {

    NSMutableArray *annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSInteger i;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < [storeLatitude count] ; i ++ ) {
        location.latitude = [[storeLatitude objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
        location.longitude = [[storeLongitude objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];

        MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:    [listOfStores objectAtIndex:i] andCoordinate:location];
        [annotationArray addObject:newAnnotation];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];    
    }
    [mapView setSelectedAnnotations:annotationArray];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this. It will show the title automatically.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:yourannotationpin animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U May use custom annotation view for displaying Title and subTitle without click on pin.
there is an tutorial for custom annotation view.

[This app contains the custom annotation view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *Sorry, that page cannot be found*

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find the swift version of `setSelectedAnnotations`. Below shows the title, however for multiple moving targets only the title of the last in the array will be shown until the next iteration of `didAdd`. So still looking for a more general/complete solution.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    for view in views {
        if let annotation = view.annotation, let title = annotation.title {
            print("displaying:\(title!)")
            mapView.selectAnnotation( annotation, animated: true )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

no its not possible. you must click on pin Annotation to display title.